# Are author names typically visible to reviewers for paper award decisions?

Tags: peer-review, reference-request, anonymity, awards

I wonder whether author names are typically visible to reviewers when they decide paper award recipients. (i.e. non-anonymous process)

I am mostly interested in the field of computer science (especially machine learning and natural language processing), and English-speaking venues.

Ideally, I would like to have a list of awards labeled with anonymous / non-anonymous.

Comment: I'm going to ignore the "reference-request" tag and answer from experience.  Please either explain why you need a reference (and I'll delete my answer) or else remove the "reference-request" tag.

Comment: @jakebeal I had added the "reference-request" tag as ideally, I would like to have a list of awards labeled with anonymous / non-anonymous. Shall I create the separate question focusing on the reference request? (thanks for your answer to this question)

Comment: I don't believe that your "big list" question is meaningfully answerable: nobody is systematically tracking conference awards.

Comment: @jakebeal it's unfortunately unlikely, but I guess it doesn't hurt to ask it, in case. Shall I create the separate question focusing on the reference request?

Comment: I think this question will suffice: if anyone is capable of answering, you can accept them and bump it to the top

Comment: @jakebeal Sounds good

Answer (score 6):

In my experience with computer science conferences, I have encountered two general classes of award processes:

1. Reviewers nominate for an award, and then the organizers consider and choose between the nominees.
2. After reviews have been submitted, the organizers consider the top N papers by rating and choose between them.

Sometimes the decision is made entirely from the paper and reviews, while in other cases presentation at the conference is taken into account as well.  In all of these cases, however, notice that it is the organizers and not the reviewers who actually decide the award, and the authors are generally not blinded to the organizers.  If the first procedure is followed and the conference happens to be double-blind, then nominations will be made blind, but the decision is still typically made with knowledge of the authors.